# What is the role of SCEP in iOS MDM Enrollment

Tags: ios, mdm, ota, scep

We use SCEP to issue certificates to Authorized entities, but what is the use of the certificate in iOS MDM Enrollment

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is used for:
 1. Client certificate authentication (if the MDM endpoint requires SSL)
 2. Decrypting the Encrypted Configuration Profiles (if server encrypts those).

Comment: whether the server encrypts the data or not how does device agent recognise that ?

Comment: If you're installing a normal profile, the plist contains a `PayloadContent` property. But when the profile is encrypted, the plist will contain an `EncryptedPayloadContent` property.

Comment: Thanks for the info,
The first point you said  for supporting SSL. is it 2way ssl ?

Comment: Correct. iOS does not allow MDM over non ssl traffic, so the one-way is always assumed.